# How did 'forfeit' shift to signify ‘penalty imposed for committing such a misdeed'?

Tags: étymologie

I don't understand this semantic shift, because a misdeed differs from a penalty or ["something to which the right is lost through a misdeed"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/forfeit#etymonline_v_40774). Can someone please fill in the gap?

> #### forfeit [13]

> A *forfeit* was originally a ‘transgression’ or ‘misdemeanour’. The word comes from Old French *forfet*, a derivative of the
> verb *forfaire* or *forsfaire* ‘commit a crime’. This was a compound formed from *fors-* ‘beyond
> (what is permitted or legal)’, which is descended
> from Latin *forīs* ‘outdoor, outside’ (source of
> English *forest* and related to *foreign*), and *faire* ‘do, act’, which came from Latin *facere* (whence
> English *fact, fashion, feature*, etc). The
> etymological meaning ‘misdeed’ was originally
> taken over from Old French into Middle English
> (‘Peter was in hand nummen [taken] for forfait
> he had done’, *Cursor mundi* 1300), but by the
> 15th century it was being edged out by ‘penalty
> imposed for committing such a misdeed’.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto, p 226 Left column.

Answer (score 1):

The etymologies of ([forfait](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/forfait/1)) and (*[forfait](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/forfait/2)*) differ so one hasn't really shifted into the other.